# Android In-App Billing Foreign Country

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm currently trying to integrate a service that will enable my users to purchase In-App virtual products.

However I've tried to integrate Google's In-App Billing service into my app, however it requieres a Google Checkout Merchant account, which is not supported in South Africa for some reason. So I can scrap that idea unless I have a bank account in one of the supported countries?

I'm just having a look PayPal. Is this a good option?

So my questions:
Is there anyway I could still somehow get Google In-App billing to work?
Is PayPal a good option? (I'm guessing it would limit potential customers)
Are there any other good options for IAP?

Comment: Using paypal is a greate way and most secure.You can go for it.

Comment: Do you have any past experience with it?

Comment: If you are talking about paypal then you can find the paypal library for android development.

Answer (score 0):

Read the developer agreement and consult a lawyer if necessary, but simply put all billing for *virtual* items needs to go through Google Checkout/Wallet. PayPal would be against those terms if you distribute through Google Play.

The only reliable way is open a developer and bank account in a country that supports paid apps.

Comment: Realy?! Why does Google make it so difficult for me... :( All I want to do is earn some pocket money on my game. I'm guessing it will be really difficult to set up a bank account in a country that supports paid apps as a foreign minor... Perhaps I should write an email to Google.

Comment: I just noticed that there is a PayPal app on Google Play, and I'm sure they are not processing their user transactions through Google's services, hence I could use PayPal? However if Google is unhappy about me using PayPal for IAP, would they take the app down or notify me first?

Comment: The PayPal app lets you manage your PayPal account, not buy apps. I don't know what Google's policies are, but it appears generally quite hard to get in touch with them once they ban you. Therefore consult a *real* lawyer before going forward.

Comment: That sounds like such a mission, all I want to do is sell some virtual items. Thanks anyways.